# XPages Ext Lib - create OSGI plugin for JDBC driver for iSeries

Tags: jdbc, xpages-extlib

I have downloaded the JTOpen toolbox (http://jt400.sourceforge.net/) and am using the XPages Ext Lib "JDBC Driver Plug-in Wizard" to create an OSGI plug-in for JDBC access to iSeries files.

On the Wizard I left the Type drop-down empty and manually entered a Class of "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver" - I think this is the correct class, but not 100% certain. I added the JAR file jt400.jar from the java6 directory of JTOpen.

After importing the generated site.xml into the Update Site database and restarting the HTTP task I issued a "tell http osgi ss com.ibm.as400" command - but do not see the OSGI plugin listed.

I have previously been through the same process for a JDBC driver for SQL Server and that works fine. I suspect I'm either using the wrong jar file or have the wrong class name. The Domino server is 9.0.1 FP1.

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you issue the command `tell http osgi diag com.ibm.as400`, that will tell you of any dependency issues.

Comment: Thanks Paul. That gives "Cannot find bundle com.ibm.as400" - which I guess makes sense given that the ss command didn't list anything. I've got something wrong - just not sure what!

Comment: Is com.ibm.as400 the plugin name? If it is, it would suggest HTTP hasn't restarted correctly, otherwise the plugin should be found.

Comment: No - that's my problem! The OSGI plugin is loaded correctly. If I use the correct name it is listed by the "ss" command. Thanks, Paul